# Converting Tuple Index to a Datetime index

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, tuples

I am averaging my data frame by month/day/year etc and have run into trouble with my index being converted from Datetime to Tuple. I want to have my index in Datetime so that I can export it to excel for other non-python users and have it still make sense with timestamps.

This what my Df look like:

```
Index   Date Time       Value
1       1/26/2016 07:00 100000.0    
2       1/26/2016 07:00 1000000.0   
3       1/26/2016 14:46     98.52
6       1/26/2016 14:46     Nan
8       1/26/2016 14:48     100.94
11      1/26/2016 14:48     Nan
```

This is the snippet I have issues with:

```
df_cv_1_grouped = df_cv_1.set_index('Date Time',drop=False)
year_hour_means = df_cv_1_grouped.groupby(
    lambda x: (x.year, x.month, x.day, x.hour)).mean()
```

The output is great, but the index is now a Tuple (the "Value" column is irrelevant.)

```
Index               Value
(2016, 1, 26, 7)    1.5
(2016, 1, 26, 14)   22.7
(2016, 1, 26, 15)   125.3
(2016, 1, 26, 16)   288.5
```

I can't seem to find a way to get it back into datetime (or keep there) in a simple manner.

Comment: Can't do more at the moment but try passing as_index=False to the groupby method.

Comment: See the [docs for `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby)

Comment: avoid doing this "Date Time", rather use "DateTIme". No space between words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can convert `index` [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_period.html), [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `index` (`level=0`) and then convert [`to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp.html):

```
df_cv_1_grouped = df_cv_1.set_index('Date Time', drop=False)

df_cv_1_grouped = df_cv_1_grouped.to_period('H')
print (df_cv_1_grouped)
                           Date Time       Value
Date Time                                       
2016-01-26 07:00 2016-01-26 07:00:00   100000.00
2016-01-26 07:00 2016-01-26 07:00:00  1000000.00
2016-01-26 14:00 2016-01-26 14:46:00       98.52
2016-01-26 14:00 2016-01-26 14:46:00         NaN
2016-01-26 14:00 2016-01-26 14:48:00      100.94
2016-01-26 14:00 2016-01-26 14:48:00         NaN

year_hour_means1 = df_cv_1_grouped.groupby(level=0).mean()
print (year_hour_means1)
                      Value
Date Time                  
2016-01-26 07:00  550000.00
2016-01-26 14:00      99.73

print (year_hour_means1.index)
PeriodIndex(['2016-01-26 07:00', '2016-01-26 14:00'], 
dtype='int64', name='Date Time', freq='H')

year_hour_means1 = year_hour_means1.to_timestamp()
print (year_hour_means1)
                         Value
Date Time                     
2016-01-26 07:00:00  550000.00
2016-01-26 14:00:00      99.73

print (year_hour_means1.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-26 07:00:00', '2016-01-26 14:00:00'], 
dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date Time', freq=None)
```

[Converting between representations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-between-representations).

Comment: I tried, why does not 15T or 30S work for period, Or does it. And its user error.

Comment: I think if you want convert to other frequencies use [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

Comment: @jezrael thanks a bunch! This totally worked, and I'll look more into grouping by period instead of the lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

First you should use [pd.to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert `Date Time` values to `datetime` then you can use [set_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

```
df['Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time'])
df2 = df.set_index('Date Time')
```